# Find the minimizer of over $t\in [0,1]$ $\phi((1-t)x+t\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|})$, where $A$ is positive semidefinite and $\phi$ is quadratic.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms

Let $A$ be a positive semidefinite matrix, and define the following quadratic form $$\phi(x):=-\dfrac{1}{2}x^{\intercal}Ax.$$ I want to compute the following minimizer: $$\arg\min_{t\in [0,1]}\phi\Big((1-t)x+t\dfrac{Ax}{\|Ax\|_{2}}\Big),\ \text{where}\ \|x\|_{2}\leq 1.$$

---

We define $g(t):=\phi((1-t)x+t\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|_{2}})$.  My idea is to simply write it out and compute the derivative. Note that $$-2g(t)=(1-t)^{2}x^{\intercal}Ax+2t(1-t)\|Ax\|+t^{2}\dfrac{x^{\intercal}AAAx}{\|Ax\|^{2}}.$$ Hence, $$-2\dfrac{dg}{dt}=-2(1-t)x^{\intercal}Ax+2(1-2t)\|Ax\|+2t\dfrac{x^{\intercal}AAAx}{\|Ax\|^{2}}.$$

I don't know how to solve $\frac{dg}{dt}=0$... Am I heading the wrong way?

Comment: $\frac{dg}{dt}$ is linear in $t$, I don't see the difficulty?

Comment: @Rammus Yeah you are right, the thing is that in my case, I kinda expect $t=1$...

Comment: Are you not looking for the maximum? Otherwise since $\phi$ is a concave quadratic, one would then expect that the minimum occurs at the end points of the line segment, i.e. $x$ or $Ax/\|Ax\|$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I am looking for the minimum. Wow, in fact, you mean in this case it is either $t=0$ or $t=1$? This is actually what I expect in my particular case but have no idea how to prove.

Comment: It's from the definition of concave function: for any $x,y\in V$, $\phi$ is concave iff 
$$
\phi(tx + (1-t)y)\geq t\phi(x) + (1-t)\phi(y),
$$
and equality occurs at $t = 0$ or $t = 1$. It is well known that $x^TAx$ is convex iff $A$ is PSD, thus $-x^TAx$ is concave.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Ah. I think that this is exactly what I wanted. No idea what I was thinking about. Mind posting this answer as a comment so I can upvote :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of concave function: for any $x,y\in V$, $\phi$ is concave iff
$$
\phi(tx + (1-t)y)\geq t\phi(x) + (1-t)\phi(y),
$$
and equality occurs at $t = 0$ or $t = 1$. It is well known that $x^TAx$ is convex iff $A$ is PSD, thus $-x^TAx$ is concave. From all of this, we can conclude that the minimum occurs at either $x$ or $\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}$.

EDIT: since the OP asked, in fact the minimum occurs precisely at $\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}$. To prove this, note that
$$
g'(t)=\nabla\phi(x + t(Ax/\|Ax\|-x))^T(Ax/\|Ax\|-x)=\\= -(x + t(Ax/\|Ax\|-x))^TA(Ax/\|Ax\|-x)=\\=-t\left(\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|} - x\right)^TA\left(\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|} - x\right)-x^TA\left(\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|} - x\right).
$$
This is an affine decreasing function, so it suffices to prove that $g'(0) \leq 0$, or that $x^TAx\leq\|Ax\|$, which is true from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, since $\|x\|\leq 1$. Therefore $g'(t)\leq 0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, which implies that $g(t)$ is decreasing in $t$, establishing that $g(1)\leq g(0)$, or in other words that $\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}$ is the minimizer.

Comment: Great answer. ty!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical You're welcome! :)

Comment: Just another quick question, any idea how to get rid of the solution $t=0$?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Hmm, good question. I'm not sure it can be eliminated in general. However, it would be sufficient to check if $g'(t) = \nabla\phi(x + t(x-\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}))^T(x-\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|})=-t(x-\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|})^TA(x-\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|})-x^TA(x-\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}) < 0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, which would mean the $g$ is decreasing in $t$.

Comment: Yeah. I was also heading towards this direction. Great answer! Thank you!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Glad to help! Does your $A$ have a special structure? Maybe then it's possible to prove, since we only need to check $g'(0) < 0$. I will give it a shot regardless.

Comment: The only thing I know is that $x$ has norm $\leq 1$, and $A$ is positive semi-definite

Comment: I also know that $\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}=\arg\min_{\|y\|\leq 1}\langle t,-x^{\intercal}Ax\rangle$

Comment: Thx for sticking around for this question for so long! Yeah. I think that there is no way to get rid of $0$. Given my particular application, I can disregard $t=0$. In general, we cannot. Thx again!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical I've found errors in my numerical simulation code and fixed them. After rerunning them, I've yet to find a counter example, so most likely $g(1)\leq g(0)$ holds, and I retract my previous statement (sorry about the confusion). I can try to prove it, but maybe it's better to ask a separate question about it?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much for sticking around this long!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Of course, you're welcome! It is an interesting problem.

Comment: I just saw your update. Really nice answer. I really appreciate that you've spent this much of time on my post. Bounty will be given :)

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Hehe, I appreciate that, but it wasn't necessary! Perhaps we can split with gerw, because their answer is also pretty good.

Comment: I would really love to but I can't.. It was a good time discussing with you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that the minimizer is attained at $t = 1$. The other answer already shows that the minimizer is attained at $t = 0$ or $t = 1$.

For a positive semidefinite matrix $A$ and a vector $x$ (not normalized), we have to show that
$$
(x^\top A x) (x^\top A^2 x) \le (x^\top x) (x^\top A^3 x).
$$
We make an Eigen decomposition of $A$, i.e.,
$$
A = \sum_i \lambda_i v_i
$$
and get $x = \sum_i \xi_i v_i$. By using $\eta_i = \xi_i^2$, it remains to show
\begin{equation}
(\sum_i \eta_i \lambda_i) (\sum_i \eta_i \lambda_i^2)
\le
(\sum_i \eta_i) (\sum_i \eta_i \lambda_i^3).
\qquad(1)
\end{equation}
For this, we can utilize Hölder's inequality
\begin{align*}
\sum_i \eta_i \lambda_i
&=
\sum_i (\eta_i^{2/3}) (\eta_i^{1/3} \lambda_i) \\
&\le
(\sum_i(\eta_i^{2/3})^{3/2})^{2/3}) (\sum_i (\eta_i^{1/3} \lambda_i)^3)^{1/3}
\\
&=
(\sum_i \eta_i)^{2/3} (\sum_i \eta_i \lambda_i^3)^{2/3}.
\end{align*}
Similarly,
$$
\sum_i \eta_i \lambda_i^2
\le
(\sum_i \eta_i)^{1/3} (\sum_i \eta_i \lambda_i^3)^{1/3}.
$$
Multiplication of both inequalities yields (1).